# VS Code: How to connect a same remote container in different local machines?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers, remote-connection

I have started a container in a remote server and connected it to the vscode. I have another local machine that also needs to connect to the same container in the same way (also use the "attach visual studio code" command in Fig. 1).
[image: Fig. 1]

However, when local machine B attaches to the container, the connection in local machine A will be lost immediately. Similarly, if I reload the window in machine A, the connection in machine B will be lost.

So, is there any solution to the problem? Can I keep the connection with different local machines at the same time?

The document of vs code does not discuss this problem.